# XSLT 1.0 Split long string respecting carriage return

Tags: xslt-1.0

I need to transform this kind of text element,

```
    <text>Testataan miten systeemi tekee rivinvaihtoja kun niitä ei ole erikseen lisätty. Tämä teksti kirjoitettu putkeen ilman rivinvaihtoja. Tämä teksti lisätty muistilappuun, mutta vieläkään ei tehty yhtään rivinvaihtoa tarkoituksella. Ilmestyykö sellaisia kuitenkin, jäädään odottamaan..

- tämä teksti lisätty ja laitettu pari rivinvaihtoa
- ja toinenkin rivi alle</text>
```

into this kind of structure

```
<_-WRP_-SF_1SACTTXTL SEGMENT="1">
    <TDFORMAT>=</TDFORMAT>
    <TDLINE>Testataan miten speedo tekee rivinvaihtoja kun niitä ei ole erikseen lisätty. Tämä teksti kirjoitettu putkeen ilman rivinvaihtoja. </TDLINE>
  </_-WRP_-SF_1SACTTXTL>
  <_-WRP_-SF_1SACTTXTL SEGMENT="1">
    <TDFORMAT>=</TDFORMAT>
    <TDLINE>Tämä teksti lisätty muistilappuun, mutta vieläkään ei tehty yhtään rivinvaihtoa tarkoituksella. Ilmestyykö sellaisia kuitenkin, jää</TDLINE>
  </_-WRP_-SF_1SACTTXTL>
  <_-WRP_-SF_1SACTTXTL SEGMENT="1">
    <TDFORMAT>=</TDFORMAT>
    <TDLINE>dään odottamaan..</TDLINE>
  </_-WRP_-SF_1SACTTXTL>
  <_-WRP_-SF_1SACTTXTL SEGMENT="1">
    <TDFORMAT>*</TDFORMAT>
    <TDLINE>- tämä teksti lisätty ja laitettu pari rivinvaihtoa</TDLINE>
  </_-WRP_-SF_1SACTTXTL>
  <_-WRP_-SF_1SACTTXTL SEGMENT="1">
    <TDFORMAT>*</TDFORMAT>
    <TDLINE>- ja toinenkin rivi alle</TDLINE>
  </_-WRP_-SF_1SACTTXTL>
```

As you can see first part consists a long string and at the end there is couple lines with carriage returns. Long string needs to be splitted on every 132 characters with tag TDFORMAT value "=" and lines with carriage return with tag TDFORMAT with value "*". I have achieved almost working solution with this template

```
<xsl:template name="split">
        <xsl:param name="text" select="."/>
        <xsl:if test="string-length($text) > 0">
            <xsl:variable name="output-text">
                <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(substring-before(concat($text, '&#xA;'), '&#xA;'))"/>
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="string-length($output-text) &lt; 132">
                    <xsl:if test="normalize-space($output-text) != ''">
                        <_-WRP_-SF_1SACTTXTL SEGMENT="1">
                        <TDFORMAT>*</TDFORMAT>
                            <TDLINE>
                                <xsl:value-of select="$output-text"/>
                            </TDLINE>
                        </_-WRP_-SF_1SACTTXTL>
                    </xsl:if>

                    <xsl:call-template name="split">
                        <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text, '&#xA;')"/>
                    </xsl:call-template>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:if test="normalize-space($output-text) != ''">
                        <_-WRP_-SF_1SACTTXTL SEGMENT="1">
                            <TDFORMAT>=</TDFORMAT>
                            <TDLINE>
                                <xsl:value-of select="substring($output-text, 1, 131)"/>
                            </TDLINE>
                        </_-WRP_-SF_1SACTTXTL>
                    </xsl:if>
                    <xsl:call-template name="split">
                        <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring($text, 132 )"/>
                    </xsl:call-template>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
```

Problem is the remaining chracters of long string(less than 132) which produces TDFORMAT tag with value "*".

Comment: Is it possible for any of the "short strings" to be longer than 132 characters - and if yes, do they need to be split?

Comment: Actually yes and yes. I kinda realized that myself after posting the Q...

Comment: Which XSLT 1.0 processor are you using? You could really use some extension functions here.

Comment: We are investigating possibility to use XSLT 2.0, but not sure yet. Did not have time to test it so far.